# Prove $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{x + n - i}{n - i} \binom{y + i}{i} = \binom{x+y+n+1}{n}$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Prove $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{x + n - i}{n - i} \binom{y + i}{i} = \binom{x+y+n+1}{n}$. I put it into Mathematica and it gives answer. However, I have no idea how to prove it. Could anyone help me? Thanks!